# Creating web dynamic project with Eclipse EE IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am a newbie trying to create a simple web application using JSP and Mysql.
I am using following thing:

1. Eclipse EE IDE
2. Tomcat 7.0
3. Dtabase: MySQL
4. MySQL Connector

In my page I have row user add row dynamically that s work fine. I want my values should get stored in database after submit.I have searched lot on net but not find anything which can solve problem.I am giving code of current page.I know have to do connection also however I tried but not succeeded.
Thanks in advance.

**JSP & Javascript:**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add").click(function() {
              $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #name').val('');
        $("#mytable tbody>tr:last").each(function() {this.reset();});
              return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <a  id="add" href="javascript:void(0)">Add another Credit card</a>
      <table id="mytable" width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
      <tbody>
          <tr class="person">
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="name" /></td>
          <td><select>
          <option>value1</option>
          <option>value2</option></select>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
              </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                  <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
       <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to create a java servlet to do this. There are hundreds of examples online that explain how to insert something in a database. https://www.google.ch/search?q=servlet+to+store+mysql&oq=servlet+to+store+mysql&aqs=chrome..69i57.4108j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=91&espv=210&q=servlet+insert+mysql+example

Comment: @luanjot:thanks!I am aware how I can achieve this, however i am dnt knw how to places the file and where it need to created.

Comment: I would implement a persistence logic. Try [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html) tutorial with JPA and the EclipseLink implementation for instance.

Comment: @MikePhils Check this out http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jdbc/jdbc-mysql-connection-tutorial/